# Resizing an image in Xamarin forms using Skiasharp package

Tags: c#, image, xamarin.forms, skiasharp

How to force an image to have the height and width of the screen using Skiasharp package and the `SkiaSharp.SKBitmap.Resize`?

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide The image information of the desired bitmap and the resize method.
example :

```
var dstInfo = new SKImageInfo(_fixedheightint, _fixedwidthint);
mybitmap.Resize(dstInfo, SKBitmapResizeMethod.Hamming);
```

Comment: it should work , can describe more your problem , maybe providing the errors or the output may help us to identify the issues